# Which ubuntu Version should I install In this Processor type ? AMD64 or x86_64

Tags: cpu

```
root@cmovel-lb01:~# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64  >>>>>> 
CPU op-mode(s):        64-bit
CPU(s):                4
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
CPU socket(s):         1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD   >>>>>> 
CPU family:            16
Model:                 2
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               1100.000
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             64K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              512K
L3 cache:              2048K
```

Comment: Either amd64 or i386 will work on your machine.  Personally I would go with amd64.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same processor, and I am happy to say AMD64 is what you need.

Comment: Thxs for Your Help.thats starge I could install a ubuntu intel x86_64 and complete the installation.. probably that's why I can't get the updates. Anyway, am going to install a AMD64 now.

Answer (score 0):

### AMD64 OR 64 Bit Version

[image]

You can download it on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop